# Any idea why the code snippet below prints 2 and not 3

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, post-increment

I was expecting this code snippet to print 3 as the if condition is false and y++ will execute, but it prints 2, any idea why..Thanks!!

```
int x = 3;
int y = 2;

printf("%d\n", (x<y) ? x++ : y++);
```

// This prints 2

Comment: Read about post-increment and pre-increment.

Comment: `x < y` is false, so `y++` is selected. `y` is pushed onto the stack for `printf` before `y` is incremented with the `++` since it's a post-increment. *Voila!* A 2! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `y++` returns the value of `y` then increases it.

Where as if you put `++y` it would increase the value of `y` first then return it.

Answer (score 2):

`x++` and `y++` are post-increment. That is, they return the current value of the variable, *then* add one to it.

Pre-increment would be `++x` or `++y`. Those increment and then return the new value.

Both pre- and post-increment (and -decrement) are useful things when writing loop controls, which is why C supports both.

(Originally, if I remember correctly, C only supported pre-increment and post-decrement, because there happened to be instructions on the machines it was developed on which encapsulated those behaviors. But as C moved to other systems, and as people started noticing that they wanted both pre and post for both, this was generalized.)

Note that this means the `c++` language was misnamed. It should have been called `++c` -- we want it improved *before* we use it, not after!

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operators are evaluated last; this is called "post-increment." So, this:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 2;

printf("%d\n", (x<y) ? x++ : y++);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 2;

printf("%d\n", (x<y) ? x : y);
y++;
```

(`x++` isn't ever reached because of the ternary condition.) On the other hand, this:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 2;

printf("%d\n", (x<y) ? ++x : ++y);
```

would increment `y` before returning its respective value to `printf()`, so the logic would be:

```
printf("%d\n", (3<2) ? 3 : 3); // prints 3
```

Comment: Only one of the second and third expressions of the conditional operator is evaluated. So either x or y will be incremented, but not both.

Comment: @scfrench good point; edited.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a post increment `y++`, value of `y` will be used first and incremented. That is the `printf` will be passed the value before increment operation, in your case `y` is 2 before  increment and 2 will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider x++ and y++ after all the other operations of this line have been completed. So, print y and then increment x and y.